# How much does firebase charge for storage of anonymous User data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use Firebase only for reading data from Realtime Database for all the Users. As data consumption will be charged based on how many times Users read the data, We restricted the unauthorised access by providing anonymousSignIn.  But because of anonymous signIn, "User" table will be created and all the anonymous login sessions will be maintained in that table, increasing the storage of data.

Considering a huge customer base of 5 million people use the app, same amount of anonymous sessions will be created in the firebase User table. **Any information will be helpful and appreciated related to what will be the impact related to storage space (in terms of cost)if I allow anonymousSignIn.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't charge for anonymous users. You can see this in the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page, and in the [pricing section of the FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing).

If you store data for each user in your Realtime Database, you will be charged as described on the same pricing page.

---

**Update**: in 2022, Firebase introduced an Firebase Authentication with Cloud Identity option, which adds new features to Firebase Authentication, but which **does** charge for the number of users (anonymous or otherwise) in your project. Check the same pricing page I linked above for details on this plan too.

Comment: Yes @Frank van Puffelen, I understand that the authentication as such is not charged for anonymous User. But, as the data of the all the anonymous users get stored in "User" table, I am bit worried, how much it will be charged based on storage if there is a huge customer base of 5million users

Comment: There is no charge for the storage of anonymous user data in Firebase Authentication. If there was it would be shown in the pricing page that I linked.

Comment: Is this still true @FrankvanPuffelen? Because I am using anonymous users and pricing indicates that for example 6.1K/50,000 and will be billed if users crossed 50k. Also, pricing calculator also includes pricing for Anonymous MAU: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?authuser=1#tab=identity-platform. Would be great if you can clarify/

Comment: Good catch, @FahryMohammed! There's been an update on this indeed. I added some information on the new (optional) upgrade to my answer. If you have more questions about that, I recommend opening a new question for it.